# Creating a “Related pages” view which also excludes the current node in Drupal 8

Tags: view, drupal-8

Does anybody know how to this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199327/creating-a-related-pages-view-which-also-excludes-the-current-node-in-drupal-7 in drupal 8?

Thank you!

Comment: The same way. What's wrong?

Comment: There is no 'more' link with 'exclude' option...

Comment: Check my answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems your problem is that you can't find the "more" link.

1/ In your view, click on "Advanced" to unfold:

[image]

2/ Click on the filter ("Content ID" in the picture) and you will find the "more" link to unfold then the "exclude" checkbox

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much progzy. The problem was that I could not scroll more than 'administrative title' section. So I tried to open 'content: ID' in new tab and it gave me a lot of more options and also 'MORE' link. Couldn't believe that there is such a bug in drupal...

Answer (score 0):

u can also create in the node , a field of type entity reference that will refer to the related nodes.
easy and robust